# Implement user blocking user using Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm going to implement a way for users to block other users from getting messages sent to them. The idea of the app is to send text messages to random nearby people.

How I implement this:
When sending a text, you randomly get 10 nearby people, you filter out the users you've blocked and also the users that are blocking you. A random user will be picked at random from the users that are left.

What I need help with:
Since I query other users blocked list frequently I'm stuck on the way I want to implement the data structure for it to be cost-efficient.

Option 1:
Keep a blocked user list with all the users that you've blocked, like so:

```
Firebase:{
    Users:{
        userID:{
            id:
            blocked:{
                blockedUserID:
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then, when filtering out what user that is blocking me, you just query the "blocked" section for each user and check if your id is listed, if yes, filter them out.

Option 2:
Keep track, for each user who you are blocking and who is blocking you:

```
Firebase:{
    Users:{
        userID:{
            id:
            blocked:{
                IdOfUsersThatI'veBlocked:
            }
            blockedMe:{
                IdOfUsersThatIsBlockingMe:
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would rather go with option 2. You will only be needing to query once in order to know what users you should be filtering out.

My questions are following:
What option is preferred, when looking at a lower amount of data to be retrieved and fewer queries to be made?
Is there a better way of implementing this?
By putting "blocked" and "blockedMe" outside the "Users" child, will this be an improvement?

Comment: Some comments: #1/ With Option 1 you only get the users you have blocked, so you will have to go through the list of non-blocked users to check if they haven't blocked you. So probably more time consuming at runtime, compare to option 2. #2/ What happens if after removing (from the original 10 users list) the ones that you've blocked and the ones that have blocked you there is no use remaining?? #3/ For option 2, you will probably have to use a transaction when writing the blockedMe node.

Comment: @RenaudT. Thanks a lot for your response. Regarding #2, you will get a message saying no users around, search for the nearest user( that are not blocking you). Regarding #3, I was thinking of a multiple-path update in order to keep both lists up-to-date. Do you think that "blocked" & "blockedMe" should be moved outside the "Users" child? I'm not using REST API so "shallow-querying" is not an option.

Comment: If you used cloud functions, you could remove all the blocked/blockedMe clutter from the Users node, into some "blockedRelationships" node, and then have your function trigger on something like /sendMessage/{pushIdOfMessageSentByClient}, where message contains to/from/..., and then take option#1 in functions, and use a Promise.all() to resolve all possible blockers

Comment: @Linxy I'm not sure i completely got it. But isn't the to/from values already set when added to the database? If yes, what happens if "to" is set to -xi2sD and that user has blocked me?

Comment: yes I forgot you are sending to many people. 
Well I don't know how you select the 10 random users, but what I meant was to use the database to notify cloud functions so that it can handle the filtering/sending text part. You just need to pass cloudFunctions the relevant information it needs, like 'text'. You still implement whatever filtering you would have done on the client, but don't have to worry about network calls as its running on googlecloud.

Comment: I see! I think I know how you mean. While this is not exactly what I want you got me into the correct track. Thanks to you I think i know how i should solve this!. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dridia for #3, I don't think you can use a multiple-path update because the blocked and blockedMe nodes are not going to be written at the same time: the blockedMe node items are written when someone else blocks you while the blocked node is written by you. Hence a transaction for the blockedMe node, in case several users block you at the same time.

Comment: @RenaudT.  Is a transaction needed even if blockedMe will be added with unique ids? If user1 and user2 blocks user3 at the same time, they will update at different locations. user1 will be added to: user3/blockedMe/user1 and user2 will be added to: user3/blockedMe/user2.

Comment: @Dridia Ok, I understand: your data-model json schema is a bit misleading and I looked at it a bit too rapidly. By reading {} I had the feeling that your users where in the same object, hence my remark for a transaction. If they are saved in different (sub)-nodes it should be ok

Comment: @RenaudT. Yeah, looking back at my schema, I myself found it a bit misleading. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Dridia My pleasure! Have fun implementing your app! :-)